# How to specify return type and describe the return value in one-line ReST docstring?

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docstring

I know I can abbreviate the following ReST docstring

```
"""
:type flag: bool
:param flag: new value for the flag
"""
```

as

```
"""
:param bool flag: new value for the flag
"""
```

Can I abbreviate in a similar manner the following?

```
"""
:rtype: bool
:returns: new value of flag
"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. The description must be specified in `returns` or `return` and the return type in a `rtype`. Merging these into one line is not allowed.